# Восстановление GRUB

Tags: ubuntu, grub, gpt

При запуске диска с ubuntu (не помню какая версия, но не старше 16.04)

появилась ошибка

```
Minimal Bash-like line editing is supported. For the firs word, TAB list possible command completions. Anywhere eise tab list possible device or file completions
grub>
```

Начал делать по инструкции как тут:
https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_grub

Загрузился с флешки.

По команде sudo fdisk -l выводит такое

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.5 GiB, 1612648448 bytes, 3149704 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 97EC9BD5-12A2-4852-94C0-30BAB6C4FD4A

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624 960630783 959580160 457.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  960630784 976771071  16140288   7.7G Linux swap
```

По команде sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt

выводит

```
mount: special device /dev/sda2 does not exist
```

Помогите.

Comment: в описании проблемы нет опечатки? маунтишь ты sda1, а ошибка по sda2.

Comment: поправил опечатку

Comment: grub пишется на boot раздел, в твоем случае это sda1. В приведенной статье нету отдельного выделенного раздела под него, поэтому и маунтится корень. 
А вообще, попробуй воспользоваться Boot-Repair, благо он все вышеуказанное сделает за тебя